# Mypy Error : json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line x column y (char z)

Tags: python, json, django, mypy

I am running `mypy` version `0.910` against my django project in a docker container. Using this command:

```
mypy --install-types --non-interactive --config-file=../setup.cfg "$@"
```

It has been working wonderfully for the past 6 months or so, but sometimes this error arise:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mypy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(console_entry())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mypy/__main__.py", line 11, in console_entry
    main(None, sys.stdout, sys.stderr)
  File "mypy/main.py", line 96, in main
  File "mypy/main.py", line 165, in run_build
  File "mypy/build.py", line 179, in build
  File "mypy/build.py", line 254, in _build
  File "mypy/build.py", line 2697, in dispatch
  File "mypy/build.py", line 3014, in process_graph
  File "mypy/build.py", line 3089, in process_fresh_modules
  File "mypy/build.py", line 1975, in load_tree
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 4925 (char 4924)
ERROR: 1
```

All I could do to fix this issue is fully rebuild the container.
Could it be I have misconfigured something ?

Answer (score 3):

Mypy works by default in incremenetal mode with a cache that it stores in `.mypy_cache` (https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#incremental-mode), at least in my case this problem happened because the cache was broken.

`rm -rf .mypy_cache` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem when I run `mypy` inside the docker container (python 3.9.9) on Macbook with M1 processor. I guess it may be a sort of race condition like the mypy process is killed before it finishes writing to the cache file.

### Workaround

For me using the `--sqlite-cache` flag helps.